# Python 2.7 - Append processed file contents from multiple files to one large CSV file with original filename headers separating

Tags: python-2.7, csv, append, user-input

I have not done any programming in about 12 years and have been asked by one of my colleagues to help with what is apparently a basic Python 2.7 script. My question is very similar to what this person asked (though has not been answered):

[Python - Batch combine Multiple large CSV, filter data, skip header, appending vertically into a single CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382696/python-batch-combine-multiple-large-csv-filter-data-skip-header-appending-v)

I need to prompt the user for the folder path, read in each file from that folder (there are hundreds of CSV files), conduct processing, and then output the finished processing from each file into a single CSV file with the output of each file separated by a blank line and the filename of the file that it was read from. 
It would result in something like this:

CHEM_0_5
etc etc
etc etc
etc etc

LAW_4_1
etc etc
etc etc

LAW_7_3
etc etc
etc etc

Currently the script has to be edited with the name of the file it has to read, saved, and then run. Then the contents of the output file has to be manually copied into a new csv file. It is very tedious and time consuming.

This is what I currently have. Please note I have removed some of the processing from the example.

```
import time
import datetime

x = 0
stamp = 0
compare = 1
values = []


## INSERT NAME OF FILE YOU WANT TO CLEAN
g = open('CHEM_0_5.csv','r')

for line in g:
    lis=[line.split() for line in g] 

lis.pop(0)
lis.pop(0)
timestamps = []
results = []

x = 0
for i in cl:
    ## INSERT WHAT YOU WANT TO SAVE THE FILE AS
    fd = open('new.csv','a')
    fd.write(str(ts[x]) + "," + str(i) + "\n")
    fd.close()
    x = x + 1  

g.close()
```

I have been trying to re-learn python in the process of searching for answers but given that I don't really know what I'm doing I feel that this could be something to do after I've completed the task for my colleague.

Thank you for taking the time to read my submission!

Comment: Here are the basic things you should read about first, in order of descending priority. #1 How to read command line arguments, so that you can pass the file names or paths when you call the script. #2 How to list all all files (of a certain type) in a directory within Python. #3 How to use Python's built-in csv module to parse an process CSV in a more meaningful manner. It's best if you start with a blank script and and get comfortable with each step on its own, before you start combining them.

Comment: Thank you Tomalak. A good start!

Comment: Think if it makes sense to write the script so that it loops over the files, or so that it cleans one file and can be called repeatedly. It might be easier or more versatile to loop over files in a shell script than in python. And maybe you are more comfortable with shell script than with python, too.

Comment: If anyone else has some quick fix code I can add to achieve the desired outcome, that would be awesome :) I'm still in the process of learning, and though Tomalak made some good suggestions, I do have to adhere to my colleague's wishes and get this script working.